# SP 13 Unable to open PDF in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, pdf

I have a SharePoint 13 site that has PDF documents. In Chrome, I want to be able to click the link for the document and it open in Chrome. Currently, the link is unclickable in every single browser besides IE. How can this be possible? It's just an `a` tag.

Is there a site setting I need to select to enable use of links to documents in other browsers?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to donwloand and install the IE tab for Chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

Comment: I'm trying to understand why SharePoint is not allowing me to simply click a link. If I inspect the element in Chrome and click the link like I normally would; the document opens perfectly. SharePoint is preventing this click from firing and I do not understand why.